# SOLR: UniqueKeyID ID column not found

Tags: solr

I am attempting to add a uniquie id column based on the error message SOLR is throwing out to the updateCSV method.  The problem is even though I identify a column with id, and the column is in fact unique based on the dataset, it is still throwing out the same error even after going through several other posts on SO.

My data has no header row, which I have defined in my curl statement, and I have also included pipe delimited as my separator.

Error is the usual "missing mandatory uniqueKey field id"

Here is my statement,

```
curl http://ey9omprna004:8983/solr/HSIAnalytics3/update/csv?stream.file=/data04/dev/v601756/scripts/HSIAnalytics3/data/mergedfiles.csv&commit=true&stream.contentType=text/plain&separator=|&header=false&fieldnames=c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,id,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,c37,c38,c39,c40,c41,c42,c43,c44,c45,c46,c47,c48,c49,c50,c51,c52,c53,c54,c55,c56,c57,c58,c59;charset=utf-8
```

Here is the sample of the dataset

```
1|EC|NAR|HSI|000300794290||2921||RONKVA-RONKVALK-ERXG01|IP1/0.70815.1|1457824772||ifHCInOctets|2|9684|145782477200|145782567500|120676338|121769436||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||40102|||1093098|Y||903|20160312231932|
```

Comment: Does your document have any field called "id"? This is the unique field that solr is looking for. It should be defined in your schema.xml under the tag `<uniqueKey>`

Answer (score 1):

The document in the `solr` need a unique field for its identification or uniqueness

It is mentioned in the file named `schema.xml`.

You might have mentioned it and marked it as `required = true`.

And the document you are trying to index is missing with that `unique` (`id`) field
(for time being we condsider it as id field as you have not shared yout `schema.xml` file) so it is throwing the error

Add the missing id field to your document or you can remove the `required` attribute of the same field or mark it as `false`.

It would be nice if you could share the `schema.xml`, so that we can help to analyse the issue and give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have defined in your curl statement. I think c1 field is your unique id.

Change the `<uniqueKey>` tag in your schema.xml.

It must be `<uniqueKey>id</uniquekey>` currently.

Try changing it to `<uniqueKey>c1</uniquekey>`, if c1 is the field that represents unique values in your dataset.